# Spawning child processes and event-listening

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

This function scrapes data from a webpage by spawning a process that executes a CasperJS web scraping script. The spawned process outputs data to `stdout`.

This function has an event listener for `stdout` and this is how the parent process (Node) gets the scraped data back. How can I make this more modular? Also, would creating a `child_process` class make more sense?

```
function scrapeLinks(location, callback) {

    // stores any data emitted from the stdout stream of spawned casper process
     var processData = "";

     // stores any errors emitted from the stderror stream of spawned casper process
     var processError = "";

    // initialises casperjs link scraping script as spawned process
    var linkScrapeChild = child_process.spawn(casperjsPath, ['casperLinkScript.js ' + location]);

     linkScrapeChild.stdout.on('data', function onScrapeProcessStdout(data) {
         processData += data.toString();
         console.log(data.toString())
     });

     linkScrapeChild.stderr.on('data', function onScrapeProcessError(err) {
         processError += err.toString();
     });

     linkScrapeChild.on("error", function onScrapeProcessError(err) {
         processError = err.toString();
     });


    //once spawned casper process finishes execution call the callback
    linkScrapeChild.on('close', function onScrapeProcessExit(code) {

        console.log('Child process - Location Scrape:  ' + location + ' - closed with code: ' + code);

         processData = convertToArray(processData);

         // filter out non valid listing links
         listingLinks = filterLinks(processData);

         //console.log(listingLinks);

         // filter duplicates
         var uniqueLinks = [ ...new Set(listingLinks) ];

        if(uniqueLinks.length === 0){
            processError += 'No valid listings found for ' + location
        }

         logScrapeResults(processError, uniqueLinks, location);


         callback(processError || null, uniqueLinks);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think spawning a child process just to scrape for links is overkill. If you're scraping links from multiple online pages, the bottleneck isn't the processing speed but your network latency. Once you grab the page contents, scraping a page is a breeze. A single node process written asynchronously can do this easily.

Now if you *really need to* spawn that child process, then I might suggest you use Promises, arrow functions and the latest version of node to make this code a bit more compact. Use template strings to construct strings instead of concatenation. Don't forget to define `var`/`let`/`const`.

```
function scrapeLinks(location) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var processData = "";
    var errors = "";
    var command = `casperLinkScript.js ${location}`;
    var linkScrapeChild = child_process.spawn(casperjsPath, command);

    linkScrapeChild.stdout.on('data', (data) => processData += data.toString());
    linkScrapeChild.stderr.on('data', (err) => errors += err.toString());
    linkScrapeChild.on("error", (err) => errors = err.toString());
    linkScrapeChild.on('close', function onScrapeProcessExit(code) {

      var uniqueLinks = [...new Set(filterLinks(convertToArray(processData)))];

      if (!uniqueLinks.length) errors += `No valid listings found for ${location}`;

      if (errors)
        reject({ code, errors });
      else
        resolve({ code, uniqueLinks });
    });
  });
}

// Usage
scrapeLinks('http://yahoo.com').then((result) => {
  // result.code
  // result.uniqueLinks
}, (result) => {
  // result.code
  // result.errors
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However what happens if the spawned process is not launched perhaps because casperjs is not installed.                                 The close event would not fire and therefore the promise would be left pending indefinitely?

Comment: @therewillbecode I'm not sure what happens. But you're free to call `reject` whenever you have the chance.

Comment: So is it best practice to call reject whenever an error is encountered by the child process?

Comment: @therewillbecode I wouldn't call *the* best practice. Given that your caller is only handed a promise, how else is it going to know it failed?